# How to list groupings and keep pagination

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, wp-query

I have need to make a very custom query, and I'm not sure how best to approach it. Assume I have a custom post type that is called `Package` and three terms `(basic, pro, premium)` for the taxonomy `(level)`. What I need to do is list these in a loop with the premium ones first, followed by the pro ones, and finally the basics. Each grouping should be listed in a random order. I have accomplished this using three separate queries, but this makes paging basically impossible. I'm also using user input to generate this loop, so some code samples of how I should actually build the request would be extremely helpful.

Let me know if more information is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by keeping my three separate queries and building a complex system to handle paging manually. It's not ideal, but I really saw no better way to do it.